# Gather for each unique ids all values from csv in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataset like this:

```
id,LON,LAT
00x1,2.17105,41.31353
00x1,1.935983,41.04712
00x2,-5.381285,36.11647
00x2,0.830717,42.19835
00x1,10.21912,43.51599
```

and I want for each unique id to gather the columns LAT, LON in the form (expected output):

```
[00x1, [2.17105,41.31353], [1.935983,41.04712], [10.21912,43.51599]]
[00x2, [-5.381285,36.11647], [0.830717,42.19835]]
```

So far my code:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('/home/repos/master/testdat.csv')
 ids = []
 ids.append((df.as_matrix(columns=['id'])))
 #find unique ids
 unique_ids  =  np.unique(ids)
 coordinates = (df.as_matrix(columns=['LON', 'LAT']))
```

access all the ids and coordinates but I cannot figure out how I can achieve the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use csv.DictReader to process the file and use another dictionary to save the data. Convert the dictionary to list at the end.
I think it would be much easier than using pandas.

```
import csv
d = {}
with open('testdat.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        d[row['id']] = d.get(row['id'], []) + [[row['LON'], row['LAT']]]
res = [[key] + value for key, value in d.items()]
print(res)
```

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With Pandas, can combine 2 series into a series of lists, aggregate with `GroupBy`, then use a list comprehension. Given a dataframe `df`:

```
df['LON-LAT'] = list(map(list, zip(df['LON'], df['LAT'])))
grouped = df.groupby('id')['LON-LAT'].apply(list)

res = [[k, *v] for k, v in grouped.items()]
```

Result:

```
[['00x1',
  [2.1710500000000001, 41.31353],
  [1.9359830000000002, 41.04712],
  [10.21912, 43.515990000000002]],
 ['00x2',
  [-5.3812850000000001, 36.11647],
  [0.83071700000000004, 42.198349999999998]]]
```